# Implementing a create function for a Serializer class containing foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So, this is how i have implemented the class:

```
class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        venue = Team(
            name=validated_data['name']
            #I know this is wrong but i just wanted to demonstrate what is it that i need to get done
            #city is the foreign key referencing to the model City
            city=validated_data['city']
        )
        venue.save()
        return venue
```

So i have a model for venues, and each venue has to be associated with the model city. I am new to the REST Framework and i can't figure out a way to create an instance of the venue model while setting the value of the city field. Can someone please help me with this?

Than you

Comment: Can you share your models and request data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield), to add a foreign key relation to the object you are creating:

```
class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=City.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = '__all__'
```

You can pass a request data like this:

```
{
    "name": "MyVenue",
    ... (other venue related data)...,
    "city": 1,
}
```

where `city` is a valid foreign key to a `City` object. This will automatically set the foreign key to the `venue` object for you, and you don't even need to override `create` to handle it.